# Angular 5 Get the immediate formGroup name of form control programmatically

Tags: angular5, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

suppose i have a form group named as "birthForm"

```
this.birthForm = this.fb.group({
            address: this.fb.group({
                id: null,
                state: null,
                zip: null
            })
});
```

Now i want the form group name of state i.e "address", how can i get the form group name

Comment: I don't know exat answer but alternatively you can create one more formcontrol address: this.fb.group({
                id: null,
                state: null,
                zip: null,
    controlname:['address']
            })

Comment: This will not work for me, Because in my scenario having multiple nested formGroups and I have created the common validation service as per below link,
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-form-builder-and-validation-management

so, I need to get the formGroup name of formControl